# Diverging color DataBar (conditional formatting) - openpyxl pandas

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, conditional-formatting, pandas.excelwriter

How can I add a conditional formatting rule on a column of numeric data, using `pandas` and `openpyxl`, which would use a different colour for the negative against positive values? Ultimately the exact same result one would get when applying the data bar rule in Excel on a column.

**Expected output**:

[image]

---

I am fairly successful in applying conditional formatting to a column that contains only positive values, using:

```
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import DataBar

rule_pos = DataBarRule(start_type="percentile",start_value=10, end_type="percentile",
        end_value="90", color="FF638EC6", showValue="None", minLength=None,maxLength=None)

wb["sheet_name"].conditional_formatting.add("K44:K48", rule_pos)
```

which returns succesfully:

[image]

---

In `Excelwriter` this can be achieved with [`conditional_format`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html#conditional-format-options) utilising `'min_color': 'red'`, and `'max_color':'green'` parameters.

I tried several different methods, for example applying both negative and positive rules with green / red data bars respectively, or adjusting the parameters of `openpyxl`'s [conditional formatting](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/formatting.html). The result that I get is the same colour, but smaller bars for the negative values. This proved to be trickier than what I expected.

Comment: I think you need the equivalents of **bar_negative_color_same** (bar_negative_color) and **bar_axis_position**  that Excelwriter provides. Don't see these in the openpyxl docs.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I tried to do, but they are not available in ```openpyxl```. So I guess I am looking for an alternative way.

Comment: In situations like this it's often to look at the source XML that Excel produces. You can usually then implement this 1:1 in openpyxl.

Comment: I also meet the same problem and haven't found a solution with openpyxl